# Apply gift card programatically

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, gift-card

I have developed a custom script to place orders in Magento. How can I apply a gift card to cart (quote) programatically? I can't see any related code.

Comment: Please add the code you are using now to create the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try below code**

```
    $giftcardAccountCode = "Abc";
    $storeId = 1;
    $quoteId = 201;

    $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote");

    $quote->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->load($quoteId);

    /** @var $giftcardAccount Enterprise_GiftCardAccount_Model_Giftcardaccount */
    $giftcardAccount = Mage::getModel('enterprise_giftcardaccount/giftcardaccount')
            ->loadByCode($giftcardAccountCode);
    if (!$giftcardAccount->getId()) {
        Mage::throwException('Giftcard Account Not Found  By Code');
    }
    try {
        $giftcardAccount->addToCart(true, $quote);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it seems to be not working. The order amount found deducted from gift card balance; but, when checked the order from admin panel, there were no gift cards shown. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake!
The admin order view shows an error ""The requested Payment Method is not available."..." Thanks!

Comment: you can up-vote if that work for you

Comment: The admin error was because of another payment issue - not related to Gift card. Now Giftcard working perfectly. Thanks!